# How would length contraction work in this scenario?

Tags: special-relativity

Two monorail car are travelling at relativistic speeds together, without accelerating. One of the cars impacts a heavy wall. From the wall's perspective, the front of the monorail is slowing down, and so it expands, pushing the rest of the monorail backwards. But from the perspective of the other car, the wall is slowing the car, thus shrinking it without providing a pushing force. What would actually happen in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The car would get crushed to at least the size of its length contracted state in its new rest frame.

Even if the material is 100% rigid, the force of the impact of the wall must travel through the material, and it does that at speed c. Thus at the very best, in the rest frame you would see the back to continue to move unaffected until it arrives a distance away from the wall equal to its contracted length.

In the other moving frame, you the final state would be the new crushed monorail that's then also length contracted at - crushed **and** contracted.

> From the wall's perspective, the front of the monorail is slowing
> down, and so it expands, pushing the rest of the monorail backwards.

The key here is that due to the finite speed force can travel through a material, the monorail would **not** expand in the walls frame because the rate at which it is crushed offsets and relativistic expansion.

> But from the perspective of the other car, the wall is slowing the
> car, thus shrinking it without providing a pushing force.

Because you're seeing crushing **and** contraction, you would see the wall providing a pushing force along with the expected 'shrinking' in this scenario.